# Why do I get this SQL syntax error? - Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Why do I get this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1?

```html
<?php
include'model.php';

global $db;
 try {
  $sql ='SELECT accounts.username '
  . 'FROM accounts '
  . 'WHERE accounts.username = '
  .$_POST[username];
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $navList = $stmt->fetchAll();
  $stmt->closeCursor();

  header('location: ./view_cms.php');


 } catch (PDOException $exc) {
   echo $exc->getMessage();
  // header('location: ./view_error.php');
  exit;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: is your username a `varchar` ?

Comment: Can you show us the SQL statement only?

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to wrap strings in single quotes in the `WHERE` clause. You also need to access `$_POST` entries with a quoted string key:

```
$sql = "SELECT accounts.username ".
       "FROM accounts ".
       "WHERE accounts.username = '".$_POST["username"]."'";
```

Plus, this is the reason why PHP based web software has a bad reputation. Sanitize your inputs, for heaven's sake!! Your `prepare` statement doesn't do anything as you're not using parameters (your statement is not a prepared statement).